@vite/client throws errors with file extension is used in Angular Dynamic Routing
I'm trying to implement dynamic routing in Angular that includes file extensions (e.g., "a.pdf"). However, I'm encountering an error related to @vite/client, which is used by @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server.
My routing configuration looks like this:
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'document/:filename', component: DocumentViewerComponent }
]


Using @nx/angular:dev-server for now
